# PFProduct data browser - unable to edit

Tags: parse-platform

I created two rows in PFProduct class. But when I try to change the screenShot or title, it is showing **Error: method not allowed**. Will I not be able to edit the values in columns once I create the object?

Regards
Aaron

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Parse's servers, and has been reported already ([bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/575243315910802/)). It was actually working fine a couple of days ago.

Hopefully they will fix it soon.